# Disable jquery dates on change of month?

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

how we can disable the jquery datepicker dates on the change of the month.
i am currently disabling it using the beforeShowDay function .

```
beforeShowDay:  function(date){     

            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
```

Now i am wanted to disable the dates when user click on  the next month ..
Any idea ?

Comment: which plugin exactly you are using? Can you provide the link? What does `unavailableDates` contain?

Comment: you can check following link  https://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

Comment: @Mehar You want to restrict the dates to a range ?

Answer (score 0):

```
The following example disables dates 14 March 2013 thru 16 March 2013.
    var array = ["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```